# How does numpy's implementation random normal distribution work?

Tags: c, numpy, random

The implementation of `numpy.random.normal` is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/src/distributions/distributions.c#L135):

```
double random_standard_normal(bitgen_t *bitgen_state);
```

I'm curious about how these lines work:

```
/* r = e3n52sb8 */
    r = next_uint64(bitgen_state);
    idx = r & 0xff;
    r >>= 8;
    sign = r & 0x1;
    rabs = (r >> 1) & 0x000fffffffffffff;
    x = rabs * wi_double[idx];
    if (sign & 0x1)
      x = -x;
```

Comment: It seems to be an implementation of the [Ziggurat algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: it was that line `#include "ziggurat_constants.h"` at the top that gave it away, eh? ;)

Comment: @KonradRudolph but how does it actually perform this algorithm? All I see is loads of bit tricks :-(

Comment: The key is the lookup into the cdf: `x = rabs * wi_double[idx]`. Match that to the Wikipedia description of the algorithm and the bit twiddles should become transparent.